# CrystalReport's Section Does not have property of AddTextObject in VS2010 with CR13

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

**Note: I am using CR13 with VS 2010.**

I am creating winform app.I want to create report dynamically,

I got reference of one of link in which the guy had created report dynamically:
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-248952.html?

I want same thing but i couldn't. I have create my report's instance as

```
 EmployeeReport empRpt = new EmployeeReport();
```

then want to add TextObject as like

```
empRpt.section3.AddTextObject("Print Date: ", 0, 890).
```

But VS2010 gives me error that:

> Error 16 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section' does not
>   contain a  definition     for 'AddTextObject' and no extension method
>   'AddTextObject'  accepting a first argument of type
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be very nice if you copy the real error message from the output of Visual Studio. The error for sure want's to tell you that the method AddTextObject does not exist. At least no method without any parameters.

Comment: @wonko79 i have edited error message.

Comment: `empRpt.Section(3).AddTextObject("Print Date: ", 0, 890")` seems to me like being appropriate according to the link you gave. You should read carefully and remember case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
empRpt.Section(3).AddTextObject("Print Date: ", 0, 890")
               ^here
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I am working on winform c#.when i write empRpt. it disaplays as like section1,section2,section3,section4,section5 not like section(1),section(2),section(3),section(4),section(5).So i write empRpt.section3  but after that i couldn't find property AddTextObject .If you are aware of this type of code.then please give me any sample or inform me what mistake i am doing.???

Comment: @surend Please, right click the `sectionX` part and click `Go to definition`. This will show you what that class can do. Could you provide a small example code which I can download and have a look at?

Comment: thanks.YOu can refer example on below link  http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/668819/Report-dont-have-any-method-to-AddTextObject